# How to import octave implementation to C++ or C#

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface, octave

I am currently working on a project that is related to machine learning. There I should import octave into C++ or C# GUI library, because the octave contains a bit of coding there is a huge project after that.

I wonder how I call the octave implementation into C++ and work there as a C++ function also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is [Dynamically Linked Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Dynamically-Linked-Functions.html#Dynamically-Linked-Functions).

> Octave has the possibility of including compiled code as dynamically
>   linked extensions and then using these extensions as if they were part
>   of Octave itself. Octave can call C++ code through its native oct-file
>   interface or C code through its mex interface. It can also indirectly
>   call functions written in any other language through a simple wrapper.
>   The reasons to write code in a compiled language might be either to
>   link to an existing piece of code and allow it to be used within
>   Octave, or to allow improved performance for key pieces of code.

For the reverse, [see here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs).

Comment: right thanks for the answer. But i want to call octave code into C++ interface

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an Octave program into C++, with the help of a library/toolkit such as [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) -- its functions are very similar to Octave (and Matlab) functions.